# How to mock a java.util.Map in groovy using map coercion?

Tags: groovy, mocking, coercion

I am trying to mock Map using groovy map coercion.
I have tried various variations of the code bellow but the result was always null.

```
Map<String, String> map = [get: {String  k -> "echo"}] as Map<String, String>

println map.get("a")
```

If I use `map = {"echo"} as Map<String, String>` it works.

Any ideas on how to make the first version work?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with doing a straight coercion like that is that the `Map` that redefines `get` is already a `Map` and there's a check in the [Groovy source](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L6564) coercion that says if what you're trying to do is coerce something like a `Map` into a `Map` then just cast it normally instead of trying to create proxy to the interface as you want.

To get around this you can make your mock object a different type than `Map`, like an `Expando`, then it'll coerce into your interface type:

```
Map<String, String> map = new Expando([get: {String  k -> "echo"}]) as Map<String, String>
assert map.get('a') == 'echo'
```

Comment: Okay, so the code above works, but not for the original reason I thought it should. The `Map` as `Map` doesn't work for the reason I stated, but I have to figure out what mechanism allows the above code to work.

Comment: Haven't found the relevant source path that makes this work, but there is an article about using Expando for mocking that might prove useful: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Developer+Testing+using+Maps+and+Expandos+instead+of+Mocks